# How can you hide the title tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css, element

```
<article id="node-13" class="node node-article node-promoted node-teaser contextual-links-region clearfix" about="/fos/node/13" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document">

<header>

<h2 class="title" property="dc:title" datatype="">

 <a href="/fos/node/13">TITLE GOES HERE.....</a>

</h2>

</header>

</article>
```

I need to hide the title using CSS.

How can I do that...

As I am totally new to CSS kindly advice how to do this..

**UPDATE:**

For the unique article id

if we give title:hidden it will not display for all nodes.

**In my case it should not display only for specific nodes.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it `display:none;`:

```
article#node-13 h2.title { display: none; }
```

Alternativly use `visibility:hidden;`

```
article#node-13 h2.title { visibility:hidden;}
```

**display:none** means that the the tag in question will not appear on the page at all - rhere will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.

**visibility:hidden** means that unlike **display:none**, the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the element from the flow of the page:

```
display:none;
```

To hide the element but keep it in the flow of the page:

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `article#node-13 h2.title { display: none; }`, this will only hide the title element if it is inside node 13,

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/2QQDd/

If you would like to hide the entire article then you could do this: `article#node-13 { display: none; }`.

Please note that `display: none;` completely removes the element from the page flow, this means that the element will not only be invisible but it will completely collapse.

If you would like to merely hide the element and not "collapse" it then you should use `article#node-13 h2.title { visibility: hidden; }`. As you can see in the demo, it still takes up space above the second link,

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/wwRsa/