# Hide default title tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

We can see above images, on hover of "create" button, two tooltips are coming. here I dont want default tooltip (small one below).

**I want to show only my customize tool tip**

My Code:

```html
<style>
button[title]:hover:before {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 2px 2px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
   top: 320px; 
  z-index: 20;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
  </style>

<button onclick="setActionAndSubmit('id_form_workitem_create', 'create');" title="please fill all mandatory fields">
           Create
</button>
```

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746767/hide-title-from-tooltip

Comment: thanks.. worthful link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small tooltip that appears is being displayed because you set the `title` attribute in your DOM node. In the following JSFiddle, the solution proposed is to change the attribute that holds the tooltip content in the button and in the CSS.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nw4t9s0j/)

Answer (score 0):

The one that you want to take out is coming from your title attribute - if you remove that attribute it'll get rid of it, but you'll have to change your selector and hard-code your content, since both of those are relying on the title being there.